# Locker-Service: Is documentation about the white-listed subset of supported Javascript-features available?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

Not sure, if documented anywhere, but there an exact specification what Locker-Service will NOT block?

In particular, which of the following things will be possible with Locker-Service enabled:

- window.addEventListener() with otherWindow.postMessage() to establish secure communication over iframes-borders
- window.setTimeout()
- window.setIntervall()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can view it here:-

[**Locker Service API Viewer**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer)

- [Secure Document](http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/secureDocument.app?aura.mode=DEV)
- [Secure Element](http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/secureElement.app?aura.mode=DEV)
- [Secure Window](http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/secureWindow.app?aura.mode=DEV)

Comment: As far as this look here http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/secureWindow.app?aura.mode=DEV window.addEventListener() might work - but I can't really be sure without trying.

Comment: Yes window.addEventListener() is fully supported as per the doc. Please do not go by what the Lightning CLI tool says is supported as it us woefully out of date (that is being addressed).

Answer (score 1):

We have just updated the API viewer to make it faster, more concise, and more readable:

[LockerService API viewer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer)