# document.getElementById("myID").getComputedTextLength() is not a function

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I have developed a lightning component, I am using following `JavaScript` methods
`.getComputedTextLength()`
`.getScreenCTM()`
`.getTotalLength()`
`.getBBobx()`
I am getting following errors

> getComputedTextLength is not a function
>   getTotalLength is not a function
>   getTotalLength is not a function

While `.getBBobx()` is working fine.
Note: I am getting those error when locker service enabled

Comment: Check [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/153323/29317) out. Also, I suppose `getTotalLength()` has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength).

Comment: what about other's?

Comment: your answer's links are broken

Comment: I'm still able to access it. Just try loading the same once again.

Comment: @ozil are you using above methods in init method?

Comment: @Manjot Singh yes

Comment: Actually that is a problem .. even we try to use some js Methods on element in init they didnot work. we changed our logic to call that method on change. can you try to run your js code on Onchange Event or any other event.

Comment: @SE_User  I am not able to find any of above methods either in `SecureDocument vs HTMLDocument Compatibility Table`  or  `SecureWindow vs Window Compatibility Table` or `SecureElement vs HTMLElement Compatibility Table` link

Answer (score 2):

LockerService was missing a number of SVG elements and their associated methods/properties. This has been fixed in the Summer '17 major release.

Just make sure the methods are being called on the correct SVG types. `getComputedTextLength`, for example, should be called on [SVGTextContentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTextContentElement).